# How to get customer phone from order shipping data?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, orders, shipping, customer

How to get customer telephone number mentioned in order shipping address?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone();
```

Answer (score 5):

Ganesh,you can fetch customer phone no from  order shipping address by usig below code:

```
$orderOBject->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone();
```

If  `type of order  is virtual` then you `does not get telephone no` from shipping address.Because magento does **not save shipping address for virtual order**
.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
$Phone = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()
    ->getPrimaryBillingAddress()
    ->getTelephone();
```

Comment: This work if you need to display on account section .for order this not work